# How can we post Same content on each site in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

1
down vote
favorite

I am using Expression engine Multiple site management system I have developed three site using this are :-

```
1)www.exampleone.com
2)www.exampletwo.com
3)www.examplthree.com
```

Now I want to post data of www.exampleone.com to another two website listed above,everything is ready i am able to post data on theses three website separately but I want to post data of first site to other two. Channels and channel fields of three sites are same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You mention using MSM, so are you using the `site` parameter?

[Docs here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/managesites.html#id1)

In sites 2 and 3, simply specify `site="websiteA"` in your `exp:channel:entries` tag pair to output content from the first site. This avoids duplicating the content in the database across all three sites.

Might want to consider using Canonical meta pointing to the original site to avoid SEO penaulties for [duplicate content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content).

Answer (score 0):

This would be a <strike>good</strike> perfect use case for Multi Site Manager.

<strike>It sounds like you haven't gone that route though and retrofitting MSM can be a bit of a pain as far as I remember (only done it once).</strike>

Using MSM you would need to:
1. Set up the channel in exampleone
2. In your channel:entries tags on the other sites add the site's ID to the channel parameter.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="exampleone:news"}
```

If you wish to mix these entries in with some from the other sites you may want to also read about orderby and multi site manager.

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#channel-entries-orderby

Alternatively you could perhaps publish an RSS feed of the stories from site exampleone and pull them into the other two sites.

1. Create an RSS template on exampleone that uses a standard channel entries tag pair to write out the data in an RSS format.
2. Install something like Feed Parser on the other sites and give it the URL of your RSS feed from exampleone.

Comment: I should read the question properly! You are using MSM... I'll update my answer.